# Using folium on geopandas data in polar coordinates

Tags: python, leaflet, geospatial, geopandas, folium

I'm currently struggling with folium and a dataset using a polar CRS. While it is easy to load as a Geopandas GeoDataFrame, convert to epsg 3857 and display in a folium map, there doesn't seem to be an option to align the map to anything but traditional projections.

Therefore, all my polygons appeared warped due to the reprojection: [image: sample image of folium html page]

Usually, I would solve this using a polar projection, which my original data already is in (in this case, EPSG:9354; IBCSO South Polar Projection centered on the south pole and standard parallel at -65°). In a proper GIS, it looks like this:
[image]

Now, I considered treating the data as generic data and using the 'Simple' settings for the folium map crs option, plotting the projected coordinates as they are on the map - but that seems to lead to the same warped results.
A quick browse through the internet mentions a couple of people who complained about the same issues a while back, but there doesn't seem to be many answers.
Has anyone ever found a solution on how to either get folium to plot data with polar CRS in a reasonable way without distortion?
As long as it is interactive, I am not too limited on using folium - but apparently none of the other popular api's (plotly + dash etc.) seem to be able to fulfill my need.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some sample data we can play with? You may also check Holoviews/Geoviews project, that may be able to give you an interactive map in a proper projection.

Comment: use of **Simple** without a tile may work.  difficult to investigate without any sample data